# описать структуру при помощи union и enum С++

Tags: c++, структуры, enum, union

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с использованием union и enum.

Моя задача:

Описать структуру с именем TRAIN, содержащую поля:

- название пункта назначения;
- номер поезда;
- время отправления.
  Написать программу, выполняющую следующие действия:
- ввод с клавиатуры данных в массив, состоящий из 9 структур типа TRAIN;
- вывод на экран информации о пункте назначения, в который отправляется поезд, номер которого введен с клавиатуры;
- если таких поездов нет, вывести соответствующее сообщение.

Я знаю, что такие задачи вы видели не раз, но у меня нет другого выхода как обратиться к вам. Совсем не понимаю, как применить здесь вышеперечисленные union и enum. Если можно, напишите код, чтобы я смог разобрать. Уровень у меня не очень((((((((

код без union и enum написать смог вроде как, но не думаю, что он как-то здесь поможет

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте разберемся, что вообще есть и что такое union и enum

1. enum - это перечисляемый тип (https://ravesli.com/urok-58-perechisleniya-tip-enum/)

например тип, который может принимать 3 значения - красный, зеленый и синий

```
enum EColors {
    red,
    green,
    blue
};
```

в вашей задаче единственное куда можно засунуть этот enum наименее - это название пункта назначения, например

```
enum EDestination {
    Moscow,
    Muhosranks,
    SaintPetersburg
};

EDestination start = EDestination::Moscow;
EDestination finish = EDestination::Muhosranks;
```

2. union - это объединение нескольких переменных в одной области памяти (http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/obedineniya)

например

```
union UNumbers {
    int num;
    char letter;
}
```

В результате в одной переменной, занимающей 4 байта будет содержаться 2 переменные num (4 байта) и letter (1 байт)

вообще в современном программировании, когда ресурсов более-менее хватает, использовать `union` еще то извращение

Что конкретно в вашей задаче можно объединить в union?
Например время отправления и номер поезда при условии, что время отправления мы запишем в 3 байта, а номер поезда в 1 байт

```
union UTrainInfo {
    char departure[3];
    int train_id;
};
```

Правда в этом случае номера поездов будут лежать в диапазоне 0x01000000 - 0xff0000, а время записывать без минут, к примеру '115' будет означать 11:50

P.S.

правда гораздо удобнее использовать просто структуру с соответствующими типами

```
struct TrainData {
    std::string destination; // пункт назначения
    int         id; // номер поезда
    int         departure; // время отбытия
};
```

Comment: что-то мне кажется, вы перепутали `union` и `struct`. В объединении поля располагаются с одного адреса, и хранить в одной переменной одновременно и номер поезда и время никак не получится. В объединение можно положить или одно, или другое.

Comment: ну почему же - нам просто для получения id поезда надо будет делать traininfo.id >> 24

но опять же мы можем указать какие биты использовать (не написал), например: `unsigned int id:8, unsigned int time: 24`, но вообще для данной задачи `union` - это еще то извращение, но может в этом и заключается задача?

Comment: потому что записав одно поле, вы сотрете другое. То, что Вы описываете здесь: `unsigned int id:8` - это битовые поля, используются, обычно, в структуре, и обычно для реализации чего-то на уровне железа. В объединении Вам это не поможет.

Comment: да проверил, действительно не получится :( тогда вообще не понятно как там `union` использоовать

Comment: вот тут я с Вами согласен, тоже не вижу, куда здесь можно приплести `union`

Comment: единственное, что тогда приходит в голову - хранить там время как int и как char[4] - т.е. если надо можно править поциферно, а если надо, то сразу все время, но это вообще изврат - с тем же успехом можно просто строку хранить